# Question about third Newton's law applied to nuclear fission

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, nuclear-physics, acceleration, radioactivity

My question is about the energy that is gained by fission of Uranium 235.Suppose we have a box opened on one side where the radiation is emitted...so if that side looks to the sky that box should be measued to have more weigth when opened than when it is closed by the simple fact that accelerated particles that come from the top push down the box.Now,if we leave that box opened in free space with no gravity would that box accelerate substantially after a longer amount of time?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail

Comment: For the second case you can apply *conservation of momentum*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Newton applies to radiation, whether as fission fragments, individual particles, or gamma radiation. So a lump of uranium in an open box in space will accelerate.

How much? Looking at [hyperphysics' table](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/U235chn.html#c3), we can see that most energy, $K=168$ MeV, resides in the kinetic energy of the two fission fragments. [Typically](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/U235cs.html#c1) one will have atomic mass $A\approx 97$ and the other $A\approx 137$. So if we assume one fragment is released and the other is static because it presses against a wall, the escaping fragment velocity is $v=\sqrt{2K/m}$ and it has momentum $p=mv=\sqrt{2Km}$. For  the light fragment it is $\approx 3\cdot 10^{-18}$ kg m/s and for the heavy one $\approx 3.5\cdot 10^{-18}$. In reality fragments will be randomly directed, so some of the momentum is to the side and the impulse will be smaller. But this is a rough order of magnitude calculation.

If the box plus uranium has mass $M$, total activity $A$ Bq, then it will accelerate at $a=pA/M$ m/s$^2$. For 1 g of U235 we have $A=80,011$ [Bq/g for U235](https://www.wise-uranium.org/rup.html) and it would get an acceleration of $2\cdot 10^{-10}$ m/s$^2$. While tiny, it is [measurable](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2657&context=physics_articles).

People have been looking at [fission fragment rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission-fragment_rocket) somewhat seriously: by arranging for much higher activity using a nuclear chain reaction one can get some more serious acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

I presume by "emitted radiation" you mean: radiation from radioactive decay of the fission products, leakage of neutrons, and the extremely small number of fission products themselves that escape the free surface.  In free space the total momentum of the remaining clump of particles and the emitted radiation is zero so for radiation preferentially in one direction from a free surface, the remaining clump of particles has a net momentum in the opposite direction.  That is, in the center of momentum system the total momentum remains zero.  So yes, the clump of remaining particles accelerates.

A simple analogy is a cannon on a frictionless surface continually firing cannon balls in one direction, although changes in (rest) mass are proportionally much smaller than for the fission case, hence the need for the center of momentum frame instead of the center of mass frame for the fission case.